# sort data between many table django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

[image]

Here is my class diagram. I receive a lot of data in Product table with differente type. When i receive the data i want to sort it in inherit tables.
Example: if type is "example1" she will put herself automaticly in table Example 1.

```
class ProductModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"



class ProductViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        permission_classes  =(permissions.IsAuthenticated, permissions.IsAdminUser)
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer
        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
        filterset_fields = ['desination']

        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data,list))
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                self.perform_create(serializer)
                headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

I don't know what to do. I am blocked. Any help ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?